# Bernoulli differential equation help?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the equation $$3xy' -2y=\frac{x^3}{y^2}$$ It is a type of Bernouli differential equation. So, since B. diff equation type is 
$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n$$
I modify it a little to:

$$y'- \frac{2y}{3x} = \frac{x^2}{3y^2}$$

$$y'-\frac{2y}{3x}=\frac{1}{3}x^2y^{-2}$$

Now I divide both sides by $y^{-2}$. What should I do now?

Answer (score 4):

$$\text{We have $3xy^2 y'-2y^3 = x^3 \implies x (y^3)' - 2y^3 = x^3 \implies \dfrac{(y^3)'}{x^2} + y^3 \times \left(-\dfrac2{x^3}\right) = 1$}$$
$$\text{Now note that }\left(\dfrac1{x^2}\right)' = -\dfrac2{x^3}. \text{ Hence, we have }\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{y^3}{x^2}\right) = 1\implies \dfrac{y^3}{x^2} = x + c$$
$$\text{Hence, the solution to the differential equation is }\boxed{\color{blue}{y^3 = x^3 + cx^2}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that in any Bernoulli OE, $$y'+p(x)u=q(x)y^n,~~n\neq1,0$$ you can set $w=y^{1-n}$ and then you have to solve the following linear OE instead: $$w'+(1-n)p(x)w=(1-n)q(x)$$

Comment: +▒░░nice░work░░▒✔

Comment: @flashdesign2550: I did nothing more than Bill.

Comment: $\large +1 \;\;\mathcal{Hello}\; !\;$